# Использование регистра сдвига в шифре "Кузнечик" (режим CBC)

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование

Возник вопрос по реализации регистра сдвига, при использовании режима простой замены с зацеплением, в шифре "Кузнечик" (ГОСТ Р 34.13-2015): почему этот регистр собирается из двух блоков - первый блок взят из последовательности бит, которая еще не прошла шифрование предыдущим раундовым ключом, и второй блок взятый из последовательности уже зашифрованой?

Есть ли какой-то смысл в таком заполнении регистра сдвига? Или же достаточно будет, без ущерба для конфиденциальности шифртекста, заполнять регистр сдвига только целым блоком шифртекста из предыдущего раунда шифрования?

Схема шифрования из ГОСТ:

[image: Схема шифрования из ГОСТ 34.13-2015 для шифра "Кузнечик"]